# How to fix postfix: Sender address rejected: need fully-qualified address (in reply to RCPT TO command))?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I've installed dovecot, postfix and roundcube on an ubuntu 12.04 box.
The system is basically working - i.e it is able to send/receive mails to/from other domains.

However, some domains cause the following error message in /var/log/mail.log

```
Jul 15 01:59:21 one postfix/smtp[2019]: 0D0399C025F: to=<someone@destdomain.com>,
      relay=sm01.destdomain.com[x.x.x.x]:25, delay=0.56, delays=0.4/0/0.06/0.1,
      dsn=5.5.2, status=bounced (host sm01.destdomain.com[x.x.x.x] said:
      504 5.5.2 <contact@localhost>: Sender address rejected: need
      fully-qualified address (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Do you have any idea what's wrong here? I.e. How to force postfix to use "contact@mydomain.com" instead of "contact@localhost" when connecting to another mail server?

Any hints are appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`$mydomain` is used as a default value for many other configuration parameters, but it does not set the sender domain.

Take a look to the `$myorigin` parameter in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

It specifies the domain that appears in mail that is posted on this machine. The default is to use the local machine name, `$myhostname`, which defaults to the name of the machine.

For more information, see [Postfix basic configuration README](http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html#myorigin)

Answer (score 1):

Programs like "mail myself@example.com" may not use myorigin.
Instead create `/etc/postfix/canonical`

```
@local @realdomain.com
```

Add a reference to it in your `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
canonical_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/canonical
```

And activate the stuff

```
postmap /etc/postfix/canonical
service postfix restart
```

See the [docs](http://www.postfix.org/ADDRESS_REWRITING_README.html#canonical)